# DataTable setup in ember js

Tags: ember.js, datatable

I am using a datatable which will be shown if user chooses to show list view otherwise normal view will be shown. The problem I am facing is where to put datatable initialising code for example `$("#myTable").dataTable({});`. Initially I put it in view's didInsertElement hook. But I think it is not working because initially listview condition is false. Can anybody suggest any better approach?

Comment: My requirement is also to populate Jquery datatable with Ember model data. Could you please share your code if you find the solution?